# rails 3.0 encryption strongbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

In the context of rails 3.0 project, a database field must be encrypted. gem [Strongbox](https://github.com/spikex/strongbox#readme) is used for managing the encryption. The implementation follows the readme on github (see link).
The issue is that the view throws an error:

```
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

for `<%= f.text_field :my_field %>`

Is there anything special to be done to get the field decrypted on the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for Strongbox states: "In your views and forms you don’t need to do anything special to encrypt data. To decrypt call: user.secret.decrypt 'password'"

The Rails form builder does not call decrypt on the value when generating the form so that is why you will get this error. You have two alternatives:

- Set the text_field value manually for all encrypted fields, e.g.

  '<%= f.text_field :my_field, :value => user.my_field.decrypt "password" %>'
- Build a custom form generator that decrypts encrypted values when generating the form.