# Secure hidden variables in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

When I've worked with drupal, where you might normally pass variables through the client via a hidden field on a form, there was an option to use a 'secure hidden field', which meant that the hidden values you were passing through were done via the authenticity token and maintained server side, thereby preventing the user seeing/modifying them.

Is this something that's possible with rails? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Are you thinking about session variables?

Comment: I understood it was for a form. This would mean encrypt the value before rendering the form and decrypt it when you get it back.

Comment: It's not exactly session variables (but this is the closest thing I am aware of), and it isn't encrypting it via the form. The hidden values stay on the server and are tied in through the form ID on post.

Comment: Crucially, this means that the if the user introduces these hidden params into the post, they are ignored and the server side ones are always used, hence 'secure'.

Comment: Is there a reason session variables won't work in this case?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying "Form variables, except they're nothing to do with the form", or in other words "not form variables". Maybe I don't understand why these are being passed through the client. WHat is that trying to achieve?

Comment: Some details are in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314576/rails-3-0-encryption-strongbox

Comment: Gareth- that's right; really we set these up as form variables, so we would say something like f.secure_hidden or something, it would work just like a hidden field that would be 'received' on POST, except it is never printed to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails session object will accomplish what you're trying to do here. First, you should configure your Rails stack to use the ActiveRecord or Memcache sessions. This will drop a session cookie on your user's web browser, with an ID containing no data. This ID relates to a session object containing information about your user. In code, you can set this like:

```
 session[:myvar] = "data I want to store"
```

This data will never be sent over the wire, but available on the server side at any time, simply by accessing the session store like:

```
puts session[:myvar]
```

This is all done transparently to you by the Rails stack - no need for you to manually set or reference the cookie.

To further secure the session, you can require the session token to be sent over SSL. More information here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions